# how to improve performance when mulitple clients connect concurrently

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I've noticed that when more than ~10 concurrent clients request my API endpoint, response time increases significantly.

I'm using IIS 7.5 to host my MVC Web API application (.Net 4.5.2)

I've created a simple API Action to check this:

```
public SimpleResponse<bool> Get()
{
   Thread.Sleep(50);

   return new SimpleResponse<bool>
   {
       Value = true
   };
}
```

And here's how my test client looks:

```
 private static void TestClientConnections(int clients)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        for (int i = 0; i < clients; i ++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

                while (true)
                {
                    sw.Restart();
                    var res = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:98/ping").Result;

                    sw.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                }               
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);      
        }
    }
```

Console output when 10 clients are run:

```
62ms
63ms
62ms
61ms
63ms
64ms
63ms
...
```

Console output when 30 clients are run:

```
187ms
187ms
187ms
187ms
186ms
186ms
186ms
...
```

What I tried to do in order to overcome this:

1) Tried to set up System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit to big number considering that this is the client issue;

2) Tried to change thread limitations in machine.config:

```
<processModel maxWorkerThreads="200" maxIoThreads="200" minWorkerThreads="150"/>
```

3) Tried to increase max connections:

```
<system.net>
  <connectionManagement>
    <add address="*" maxconnection="2000"/>
  </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

4) Tried to make the api action asynchronous.

Nothing of mentioned above did not help me... Any ideas ?

I really need to handle at least 100 concurrent clients simalteniously.

Comment: update: the same picture is on Win8, IIS 8.5

Comment: also tested this on Win2008R2, IIS 7.5 - the same